# how to update several span elements based on user input HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a huge form with at least 200 input fields- `text/radio/checkboxes`.

I have divided this into several sections to structure it well and there is an **update button for each** section which takes the user input and persists it to the db. This is done by **Ajax** so I don't have to reload the page.

How can I easily update the `<span>`s corresponding to the input fields with whatever the user inputs without reloading the page? DO I have to do a `$("#spanid").html($("#input1").val())` on each `<span>` item or is there an easy way to do this?

Here's the code for a fraction of the form.

HTML

```
 <form id="history" name="history" action="" method="post"> 
 <table class="normal">
        <tr><th colspan="8">HISTORY</th>
        </tr>
        <tr><td style="width:200px"><b>Chief Complaint Location</b></td>
        <td style="width:450px"><b>Comment</b></td>
        <td><b> Previous</b> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>Head</td>
            <td ><input type="text" maxlength="100" name="headH" id="headH" ></td>
            <td class="data2"><span id="headSpan"><%=msmtCommentHead%></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>Neck</td>
            <td><input type="text" maxlength="100" name="neckH" id="neckH" ></td>
            <td class="data2"><span id="neckSpan"><%=msmtCommentNeck%></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>Upper Extremeties</td>
            <td><input type="text" maxlength="100" name="upperExtremetiesH" id="upperExtremetiesH"></td>
            <td class="data2"><span id="ueSpan"><%=msmtCommentUpperExtremeties%></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>Thoracic Spine</td>
            <td><input type="text" maxlength="100" name="thoracicSpineH" id="thoracicSpineH"></td>
            <td class="data2"><span id="tsSpan"><%=msmtCommentThoracicSpine%></span></td>
        </tr>
   <tr><td><input type="button" id="submitHistory" value="Update"/></td></tr>
   </table>
   </form>
```

Javascript:

```
   $(function(){
$("#submitHistory").click(function() {
    var query = $("#history").serialize();
        $.ajax( {
          type: "POST",      
          url: "/oscar/cmcc/History.do",
          dataType: "json",
          data: query  
         }); 
        document.getElementById('history_cmcc').reset();
        var date = new String("<%=date%>");
        $("#headSpan").innerHTML = $("#headH").val()+ "," + date; 

        $("#neckSpan").innerHTML = $("#neckH").val() + ","+ date; 


        $("#tsSpan").innerHTML = $("#thoracicSpineH").val() + ","+ date; 

        $("#lsSpan").innerHTML = $("#lumbarSpineH").val() + ","+ date; 

        $("#leSpan").innerHTML = $("#lowerExtremetiesH").val() + ","+ date; 

        $("#chSpan").innerHTML = $("#chestHeartH").val() + ","+ date; 
   }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your html code hurt my eyes. Tables, presentational elements. Someone needs to restructure.

Comment: Lose the table and the presentational markup and use CSS. If you have no idea what I'm talking about, you should go and read a good manual.

Comment: Take a look at Knockout.js http://knockoutjs.com/ - It allows you to bind elements on your page to Javascript objects and keep them synchronized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general you can do this:

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').find('span').html($(this).val());
});

$('input:checked').each(function() {

         $(this).closest('tr').find('span').html($(this).val());
});
```

**Update per OP comment:**

In your example if you wanted to put the label that is to the left of a radio button inside the span you could do this.  This depends on your specific requirements.

```
$('input[type=radio]:checked').each(function() {  
     $(this).closest('tr').find('span').html($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text());    
});
```

Comment: will this apply to checkboxes and radio buttons?

Comment: if you want ALL inputs just change the first part to: `$('input')` or you could specify them separately.   `$('input[type=text],input[type=checkbox]']')`

Comment: This is giving me an error saying: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMDocumentFragment.appendChild]

Comment: Here is a working demo, no problems with the code snippet provided in the answer: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/SkEvk/  You must have a different problem not related to updating spans based on the input values.

Comment: You're right. The demo is working but it's not working with my code.

Comment: How will this work for radio buttons and checkboxes? simply doing $(this).val() is writing a blank string to the span element

Comment: Instead of writing the label to the left of the radio button, can't I write the value of the checked radio button? That will make it more reliable.

Comment: @Sapphire the original code works fine.  You just need to only use it on checked radios.  A radio/checkbox doesn't have a value unless checked which is why you maybe seeing empty strings.  In that case you'd need to use a different way to get the value.

Comment: How will this work on multiple checked checboxes? Will it overwrite the span with the value of the checkbox that is last checked?

Comment: Your demo shows radio buttons. I wanted to know how it works with "checkboxes". I've edited your demo. Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/QNubP/3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/QNubP/4/  The rest of it are your specific requirements..

Answer (score 0):

```
$(':input').each(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').find('span').html(this.value);
});
```

`:input` applied for all inputs. Also can use `input`.